# [CAKeyframeAnimation setFromValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, animation, keyframe

I'm trying to animate a button with keyframeanimate with a button that I want to modify it's tintColor and buttons width constraint that I want to scale it 2x and vise versa, here is my code

```
func InitialAnimationToTutorialButton() {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.tutorialButton.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xDB4284)
                self.tutorialButtonWidth.constant = 60
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.tutorialButton.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x554E6E)
                self.tutorialButtonWidth.constant = 30
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.3, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.tutorialButton.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xDB4284)
                self.tutorialButtonWidth.constant = 60
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.4, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.tutorialButton.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x554E6E)
                self.tutorialButtonWidth.constant = 30
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })

        }) { (finishFlag) in

        }
    }
```

but when I run it , I've get an exception and like folowing:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CAKeyframeAnimation setFromValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2820e06e0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized how to solve this error. `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` should be out of blocks so I did it and fix the error, So here the correct code :

```
func InitialAnimationToTutorialButton() {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.tutorialButton.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xDB4284)
                self.tutorialButtonWidth.constant = 60
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.tutorialButton.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x554E6E)
                self.tutorialButtonWidth.constant = 30
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.3, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.tutorialButton.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xDB4284)
                self.tutorialButtonWidth.constant = 60
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.4, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.tutorialButton.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x554E6E)
                self.tutorialButtonWidth.constant = 30
            })
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (finishFlag) in

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A bug report has been filed on Open Radar for this issue https://openradar.appspot.com/32939029.

The reporter offers a few workarounds:

> 1. Not using a spring for the timing parameters
> 2. Putting the `layoutIfNeeded` call in the keyframe animation as well
> 3. Add an extension on `CAKeyframeAnimation` where you define a `fromValue` and ignore it being set

The 3rd solution is unlikely to affect your animation. You can add the `CAKeyframeAnimation` extension in Swift...

```swift
extension CAKeyframeAnimation {

    @objc func setFromValue(_ value: Any?) {
    }
}
```